# import random module in python not outputting number

Tags: python

I am trying to import random module. However every-time I run the code to check if random is working I receive <function random_score at 0x7f8a105d1f70> instead of an integer. It only happens when I try to define a function with random. What am I doing wrong?

```
import random





def random_score():

  return randint(0, 100)


 print(random_score)
```

Comment: `random_score` is a *function reference*. `random_score()` would return the evaluated value of the function. Parenthesis are important contextually.

Comment: btw you have not imported `randint` (in the current code it is not defined), so either use `return random.randint(0, 100)` or do `from random import randint` instead of `import random`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the function itself. you have to call it to get a result:

```
print(random_score())
```

Comment: this will raise an error tho, otherwise yes that is what they need to do

Comment: Yes, you also need to reference randint() correctly: `random.randint()`